# What's the difference between these two linker script sections?

Tags: gcc, linker, embedded, stm32

I have an STM32 project involving a .firmware_header section which caps off the end of my application image. I'm trying to relocate the .data section so that it occurs before the .firmware_header section, but for some reason I'm having a lot of difficulty doing so.

The following works, but breaks the script that I am using to sign the image because it doesn't know that it needs to include the .data section in the checksum calculation (LMA is in RAM).

```
  _sidata = .;
  .data_x : AT(_sidata) /* LMA address is _sidata (in FLASH) */
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .; /* data section VMA address */
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;
  } > SRAM

  .firmware_header (_sidata + SIZEOF(.data_x)):
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.firmware_header))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > FLASH
```

This does not work. Even though all the addresses (sidata, sdata, edata) are correct and the image boots, there is something wrong with the initialized data and the image usually hard fails for obvious reasons after beginning to run. Why would this fail to boot? The location of the data to be loaded into memory is the same as in the previous linker script snippit, and the location of the stored data in flash is also the same.

```
    .data_flash :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sidata = .;
    *(.data*)
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > FLASH

  .firmware_header :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.firmware_header))
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > FLASH

  .data_ram (NOLOAD) :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;
    . = . + SIZEOF(.data_flash);
    _edata = .;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } > SRAM
```

This is how I am loading data into memory from flash in the reset_handler():

```
void **pSource, **pDest;
for (pSource = &_sidata, pDest = &_sdata; pDest != &_edata; pSource++, pDest++)
    *pDest = *pSource;
```

What am I missing here? Shouldn't these be exactly identical in function?

Comment: It is not clear why your script is not working with the first solution. The first solution is the right way to go. What might be missing is for the data section to specify  >SRAM AT>FLASH to tell the linker that this section is located in flash but linked for ram. You could try this.

Answer (score 0):

The **first script** puts the bytes of all `.data` segments into its section in flash but resolves all their addresses for the run-time location in RAM; this is what your program needs. To initialize the variables, you need to copy the contents from flash to RAM, what you do.

The **second script** resolves all addresses of `.data` segments for the load-time location (if I might say so) in flash; that can't work because your program can't write into those locations when it runs. The `NOLOAD` part just increments the location pointer in RAM, without resolving addresses of initialized variables.

Please look at some initialized variable (to a value not equal to zero) in the cross reference. Using your first script it will be located correctly at some address in RAM, using your second script it will be located erroneously at some address in flash.